# 404 error in vb.net but 200 status on fiddler and postman

Tags: c#, http-headers

I am trying to consume the SugarCRM v10 on an existing website but it HttpWebRequest.GetResponse is not cooperating. When I go to fiddler4 and Postman, the url and the requestbody being the same from the code, I get a 200 response. This is my code so far (this is code in a function):

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = Nothing
        Dim Reqeuststring As String = myurl
        request = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(Reqeuststring)
        request.Method = mymethod
        request.ContentType = "application/json"

        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pstring)
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

        ' Get the request stream.
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

        ' Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)

        ' Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close()
 response = request.GetResponse()
```

I am passing the url (`http://{siteurl}/rest/v10/oath2/token`) as per API documentation and the pString is in json format, mymethod in this case is passed as POST.

Comment: Read this post. Very useful, and explains how to work around this. http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/57/getting-the-correct-http-status-codes-out-of-asp.net-custom-error-pages

Comment: Thanks, but i actually need to know what i can do to get the results i need from the application just as it does on fiddler. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you using MVC or ASP?

Comment: I am using ASP.net web forms